# Angular: change text description depending on which element was clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, components

I am using a mat-grid-list to display icons & a title, with an *ngfor. Once one of the elements is clicked, I want the description to show up for that element (which is also in the array.

My code looks like this.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="3:1" *ngIf="router.url === '/'">
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let service of services | slice:0:3; let i=index" (click)="changeState()">
    <i class="material-icons"> {{ service.icon }}</i>
    <p> {{ service.name }} </p>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
<div class="description" [@changeDivSize]=currentState *ngFor="let service of services">
  <p> {{service.description}} </p>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve when the first mat-grid-tile is clicked, it will show {{ service.description }} of the first array, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `(click)="changeState()"` to `(click)="changeState(service)"`

Then in your script, copy the value of `service` to another variable (say `viewedService`)

Then in your last div change it to this:

```
<div class="description" [@changeDivSize]=currentState *ngIf="viewedService">
  <p> {{viewedService.description}} </p>
</div>
```

In this, basically, you're only having the last div pop up if `viewedService` is filled and then displaying that value. If the user clicks on another mat-grid tile the content will be changed obviously.

Hope that helps (P.S. unsure what you're using @changeDivSize for as I'm not that long into angular)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer, it worked as expected.
To answer your question, @changeDivSize is an animation trigger I am using on the div element with class 'description' to animate the open/close of the div.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to send the selected service as an argument of changeState back to control that then changes the value of currentService.

Then change

{{service.description}}

->

{{currentService.description}}

and you can remove this *ngFor from the last div.

Obviously currentService must be in control.

I hope this helps.